# Center image exceeding margins in R

Tags: html, r, image, latex, markdown

I would like to center an image which goes outside the margins in R. Not sure if this is possible. I needed to resize it to make it bigger; it is left justified and only goes slightly outside visibility on the right margin after resizing, so if I center it by going a bit outside both margins, then it should be completely visible.

So my code is like this but doesn't work for centering:

```
\begin{center}
![](C:/Users/Moneeb/Pictures/GO_chart.png){width=130%}
\end{center}
```

I appreciate the help

Comment: What about using `width = \linewidth`?

Comment: Other than the origin of the PNG, how is this question related to `[r]`, `[html]`, or `[markdown]`?

Comment: Coz you can use html and markdown and R to solve this in RStudio; and i'm using RStudio to make the pdf

Comment: If the image itself looks okay before adding it to a PDF, then this is about `[markdown]` and [`[latex]`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/). If the image has margin issues itself, then `[r]` is fine (not `[markdown]`, et al) but you need to include the code and why what it creates is wrong. None of this seems to support the `[html]` tag.